# Comments in blade @php directive

Tags: laravel-5.4

I am learning laravel 5.4. And I have a question. If I want to add comments in blade template engine's `@php` directive area, such as

```
@php
 $a = 1;
 $b = 1;
@endphp
```

Is it just like normal php code :

```
@php
 //$a = 1;
 $b = 1;
@endphp
```

Is this right?

Comment: Yes that works.

Answer (score 0):

{{-- this is default blade comment --}}

Comment: no this cause error, i recently found that this {{-- comment --}} , laravel shows that error